# Take all data from a JTable and adding it to another Table in the same Database

Tags: java, sql, swing, jtable

I'm doing a project for school, I have two tables: "registros", "hoy". "hoy" is a temporary table, made for information added in one session with a button that inserts data into the JTable, "registros" is a permanent table of all the information added in the lifetime of the program. Now, my issue is, I want to insert all the rows from the table "hoy" and add them to the table "registros". I've tried multiple solutions to my problem from this site and others and still can't get it to work, what should I do?

Specifically, the try-catch doesn't have any issues until I try and use the "executeUpdate" function, then it gives me an exception, which makes it display an error message.

/When I press the button "Pasar" it should do what I've written above, moving all data from table "hoy" to table "registros" and I should be free of worries to erase all data from "hoy" and start from 0, adding new data./

**Maybe I should note I'm using NetBeans, I have no alternative, since I've seen ppl say that some solutions I've seen on this site don't work for Netbeans?**

### Code for the button:

```
private void btn_pasardbActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        
        
        int status = 0;
        
        try {
            
            conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/baser", "root", "");
            String query= "SELECT n,nhistoria,nya,id,sexo,f_a,f_m,f_d,e_a,e_m,e_d,pac,dep,mun,loc,d1,c1,d2,c2,d3,c3 FROM hoy";
            comando= conexion.createStatement();
            rst = comando.executeQuery(query);
            
            
            ps = conexion.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO registro(n,nhistoria,nya,id,sexo,f_a,f_m,f_d,e_a,e_m,e_d,pac,dep,mun,loc,d1,c1,d2,c2,d3,c3) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            
            while(rst.next()){
                int n = rst.getInt("n");
                int nh = rst.getInt("nhistoria");
                String nya= rst.getString("nya");
                String id= rst.getString("id");
                String sexo= rst.getString("sexo");
                String f_añ= rst.getString("f_a");
                String f_me= rst.getString("f_m");
                String f_di= rst.getString("f_d");
                String e_añ= rst.getString("e_a");
                String e_me= rst.getString("e_m");
                String e_di= rst.getString("e_d");
                String pac= rst.getString("pac");
                String depa= rst.getString("dep");
                String muni= rst.getString("mun");
                String loca= rst.getString("loc");
                String d1= rst.getString("d1");
                String c1= rst.getString("c1");
                String d2= rst.getString("d2");
                String c2= rst.getString("c2");
                String d3= rst.getString("d3");
                String c3= rst.getString("c3");
                
                ps.setInt(1, n);
                ps.setInt(2, nh);
                ps.setString(3, nya);
                ps.setString(4, id);
                ps.setString(5, sexo);
                ps.setString(6, f_añ);
                ps.setString(7, f_me);
                ps.setString(8, f_di);
                ps.setString(9, e_añ);
                ps.setString(10, e_me);
                ps.setString(11, e_di);
                ps.setString(12, pac);
                ps.setString(13, depa);
                ps.setString(14, muni);
                ps.setString(15, loca);
                ps.setString(16, d1);
                ps.setString(17, c1);
                ps.setString(18, d2);
                ps.setString(19, c2);
                ps.setString(20, d3);
                ps.setString(21, c3);
                
                
                
                 status = ps.executeUpdate();
                
            }
            
            if (status > 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registros guardados con exito");
                
                limpiar();
                
                
            }
            
                
                
            
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conexión con BD Inválida o Error");
        }
            
    }
```

---

Comment: I'm not understand your question. You talk about data in a JTable, but I don't see any code related to the JTable. The basic logic would be to get the data from the TableModel in the JTable and then execute SQL commands to update your database with the data in the table.

Comment: Don't ignore exceptions! They inform us exactly what went wrong. Unless logging is implemented, at least call `Throwable.printStackTrace()`